# Will this series converge, will its limit exist (and if so, what is it), and will its sum be $> 0$ or $< 0$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, conditional-convergence

The series : $$\lim\limits_{n \to  \infty }  \sum\limits_{k=1}^n - (-1)^{k} \ln (k)$$

We know that, for a sum $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty a_k$ to *converge*, a **necessary** condition is that : 
$$\lim_{k\to\infty} a_k = 0$$
We can write the above series as 
$$\ln(1)-\ln(2)+\ln(3)-\ln(4)+\ln(5)-\ln(6)\cdots\infty$$
It becomes : \begin{align}
& =\ln\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) + \ln\left(\frac{3}{4}\right) + \ln\left(\frac{5}{6}\right) + \ln\left(\frac{7}{8}\right) + \ln\left(\frac{9}{10}\right) + \cdots\ln\left(\bf{\frac{n}{n+1}}\right)\\
\end{align}
and $$\text{as,}\quad n\to\infty\qquad\qquad\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(\bf{\frac{n}{n+1}}\right) = 1$$ 
thus, $$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\bf{ln}\left(\bf{\frac{n}{n+1}}\right)=0\text{,}$$
that is, $$\lim\limits_{k\to\infty} a_k = 0\text{,}$$ 
So it *should* **converge**, we also observe that all the terms inside $log$ are **less than 1** so all the individual $\textit{log }$ values would be **negative** and thus making the sum of series negative.

We also observe that as $n\to\infty$ the values inside $log$ will tend to $0$ from *negative* side(because each individual $log$ value is negative)thus, the absolute value of individual $log$ values would slowly decrease, with the greatest absolute value of $ln\left(\bf{\frac{1}{2}}\right)$

But we can write the above series in another way :
\begin{align}
& = \ln(1)-ln(2)+\ln(3)-\ln(4)+\ln(5)-\ln(6)\cdots\infty\\
& = \qquad-\ln(2)+\ln(3)-\ln(4)+\ln(5)-\ln(6)\cdots\infty\qquad\qquad\{\ln(1)=0\}
\end{align}
It becomes :
$$\ln\left(\frac{3}{2}\right) + \ln\left(\frac{5}{4}\right) + \ln\left(\frac{7}{6}\right) + \ln\left(\frac{9}{8}\right) + \ln\left(\frac{11}{10}\right) + \cdots\ln\left(\bf{\frac{n+1}{n}}\right)$$
Again,
$$\text{as,}\quad n\to\infty\qquad\qquad\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(\bf{\frac{n+1}{n}}\right) = 1$$ 
thus, $$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\bf{ln}\left(\bf{\frac{n+1}{n}}\right)=0\text{,}$$
that is, $$\lim\limits_{k\to\infty} a_k = 0\text{,}$$

So it *should* **converge**, we also observe that all the terms inside $log$ are **greater than 1** so all the individual $\textit{log }$ values would be **positive** and thus making the sum of series positive.

**Now this is where it CONTRADICTS our above statement that the sum of series would be negative**

We also observe that as $n\to\infty$ the values inside $log$ will tend to $0$ from *positive* side(because each individual $log$ value is positive)thus, the absolute value of individual $log$ values would slowly decrease, with the greatest absolute value of $ln\left(\bf{\frac{3}{2}}\right)$

One may further argue that in our original expression:

$$\lim\limits_{n \to  \infty }  \sum\limits_{k=1}^n - (-1)^{k} \ln (k)$$

the series *does not Converge* as our **necessary** condition,
$$\lim\limits_{k\to\infty} a_k = 0$$ 
does not satisfy because $- (-1)^{n} \ln (n)$ tends to $\infty$ or $-\infty$ depending on the value of $'n'$ as $n\to\infty$, thus contradicting our another statement that : 'this series converges'

Now at last, how do we calculate the **limit** of this series (even an approximate value).

Edit : What would be the answer to the same question if the series would have been:
$$\lim\limits_{n \to  \infty }  \sum\limits_{k=1}^n - (-1)^{k} \ln \left(\frac{1}{k}\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple: It does not converge. It is similar to the old paradox
$$
S = 1-1+1-1+1 \cdots
$$
can be written as 
$$
S=(1-1)+(1-1)+\cdots = 0
$$
but also as
$$
S= 1-(1-1)-(1-1)\cdots = 1
$$
But if you avoid these dubious operations you see that $S$ actually oscillates between $0$ and $1$ and never converges. Your function is similar: $\ln(k)$ grows for each $k$ while $(-1)^k$ makes it oscillate more and more wildly as $k$ increases.

As you mentioned yourself, we need $a_k \rightarrow 0$. But clearly $(-1)^k\ln(k)$ does not converge to $0$ (its limit does not even exist, as it keeps going up and down in progressively larger swings).

Comment: Okay so it diverges, so can we say anything about its **sum** or its **limit**.

Comment: One more thing. is it correct to say that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\bf{ln}\left(\bf{\frac{n+1}{n}}\right)=0\text{,}$

Comment: @DostArora The limit of the sequence simply does not exist. It is correct that $\ln((n+1)/n)\rightarrow0$ but it has nothing to do with the limit of the series.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, $\sum_{k=1}^\infty -(-1)^k\ln k$ does not converge: The summand $-(-1)^k\ln k$ does not converge to $0$. Instead you considered the different series
$$ \sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\ln(2k-1)-\ln(2k)\right)$$
which is related to the original series by the fact that every second partial sum of the original is a partial sum of this new series. As you noted, we have at least $\ln(2k-1)-\ln(2k)\to 0$. However, for large $k$ we have $\ln(2k-1)-\ln(2k)=\ln\left(1-\frac1{2k}\right)\approx -\frac1{2k}$, so that the series (still) diverges - per comparison with thge harmonic series.

Comment: Okay so it diverges, so can we say anything about its **sum** or its **limit**.

Answer (score 0):

A number series is given by the pair $(a_n,S_n)$, where $(a_n)_n\subset\Bbb C$ is a sequence and $S_n:=\sum_{j=1}^na_j$ are the partial sums.

We use to say that the series converges if the limit $\lim_{n\to+\infty}S_n$ exists.

In your case $a_n=(-1)^{n+1}\log n$ and $S_n=\sum_{j=1}^n(-1)^{j+1}\log j$; at this point it's easy to see that $\lim_{n\to+\infty}S_n$ doesn't exist, by showing that $(S_n)_n$ has two different subsequences converging to different limit: just take
$$
S_{2n}=\sum_{j=1}^{2n}(-1)^{j+1}\log j=\sum_{j=1}^n\log\left(1-\frac1n\right)\stackrel{n\to+\infty}{\longrightarrow}-\infty
$$
and
$$
S_{2n+1}=\sum_{j=1}^{2n+1}(-1)^{j+1}\log j=\sum_{j=1}^n\log\left(1+\frac1{2j}\right)\stackrel{n\to+\infty}{\longrightarrow}+\infty$$

thus the limit cannot exist, and consequently the series cannot converge.

Comment: Thanks, it was very helpful.